# How do female-urination-devices perform on long backpacking trips?

Tags: backpacking, hygiene

How do female-urination-devices like the [Shewee](http://www.shewee.com/) and the [GOGIRL](http://www.go-girl.com/) perform on backpacking trips that are at least a week? Do they start smelling? Do they attract bears?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have it on good authority that the Shewee (no info on the other one) is incredibly easy to clean, as it is made of recyclable polypropylene, so all that you would want to do is give it a quick rinse with water if you need to.

As it is so highly polished, all you normally need to do is give it a shake, but I think a quick rinse may be what you want on a long trip.